# SSAS Historical data retrieve with DMX query using 'predictTimeSeries'

Tags: sql, time-series, ssas

I have created a data model using SSAS to predict futures sales and it works fine. But I want to compare my historical actual results and predicted values to get an idea about model accuracy. I was retrieving sales data using DMX query for future predictions as below.

`select FLATTENED [Shopid],
PREDICTTIMESERIES([Amount],0,2)
from [Test Festive Place]
where shopId=901`

I want to use DMX query for historical data as well. I thought something like this(below)

`select FLATTENED [Shopid],
PREDICTTIMESERIES([Amount],-2,0)
from [Test Festive Place]
where shopId=901`

But it is not working. Does anyone know how to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we set values  HISTORIC_MODEL_GAP (1) and HISTORIC_MODEL_COUNT (10) we should make sure that our all data series have enough data to build 10 historical model. If it gives an error that means at least one series have less data to build 10 historical model.